# What can I do if bash stops echoing?

Tags: bash, command-line, terminal

One of the applications I use at work sometimes screws with my bash and so I don't see my own input anymore. I.e.

```
$ echo foo
foo
$
```

becomes

```
$ foo $
```

I incorrectly tried to run `stty -echo` which made matters worse and now it stopps accepting commands all together  which put my input in some state that just causes `>` to appear every time I line break and nothing else.

What should I have done?

Comment: Try to run `reset` for a good start. Of course you cannot enter now any command into this terminal so from another one try something like `cat >/dev/pts/3` where `3` is your problematic terminal number and then hit the following keys: `ESC` `c` `ENTER` `Ctrl-D`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The usual remedy for things like this is

```
stty sane
```

The `stty -echo` should not have made this worse, as that just turns off echoing of input, and you already had that.

The fact that you say returns just causes `>` to appear means that you've started somethng that is causing continuance over the next lines, e.g. `echo '` will do that because it's waiting for the closing `'` to terminate the string. Other things will cause this as well, such as `if something`; it's waiting for the `then ... fi` part.

You could probably have hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> at that stage to stop it waiting for the rest of the command, unless the terminal was so messed up that interrupts were also not being generated.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. I tried hitting both `ctrl + c` and `ctrl + z` but didn't seem to accomplish anything.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @wurtel's answer (especially the likely explanation of the `>` problem), `stty echo` is the opposite of `stty -echo`, so you might use that. You can also use `reset`, which usually comes with ncurses packages.